# K8s pod connection with camera connected in same network

Tags: kubernetes

There is a Camera which is connected in a network switch . How can we connect the application to that camera through kubernetes pod. I have a pod running which should take video ingestion from that camera. How can this be achieved through application pod.

Comment: Is is IP camera?

Comment: Something like Basler camera

Comment: Everything that is accesible from your host, shoud be also accesible from pods unless blocked with network policies/firewall. Sometimes virtualization can also make some troubles. Can you please describe your enviroment, how are you running your k8s and what CNI are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes is used to run containerized applications. So you should first write the application to connect to camera and package that application as docker image and then you can run it as a pod which in turn spin your container in kubernetes cluster

Comment: I already have an application which connects to camera and when run with docker only with hostnetwork=true, It is able to connect to Camera. But how to do it in a k8s pod where I am using services and we cannot use hostnetwork as true. So I tried with network plugin also to connect but in vain.

Comment: How do you connect to camera in application? If camera is also in same network you shouldn't have problem in connecting

Comment: In docker.. I can connect camera to application through hostnetwork=true. So I need similar way in k8s where I cant use hostnetwork as I am using services

Comment: I am able to solve it by defining a macvlan CNI. And then used dhcp for dynamically getting IP.

Comment: When running DHCP, it gives me lease for sometime to connect to network. But later I starts getting error. For which I have to repeat below steps to make DHCP network UP.                                                                                $ rm -f /run/cni/dhcp.sock
cd /opt/cni/bin
$ ./dhcp daemon. Can anyone tell how can we increase the dhcp release time to exist till node exists or it get renewed on its own .